# How to prevent a page from scrolling, but rather have inner content scroll

Tags: html, css

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3cBmQf1jkPHD1CXpVmuW?p=preview).

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. The page should never scroll in any direction
2. Content that goes beyond its bounds should scroll, but only for that container.

I have a main content area that when its contents become too wide the horizontal scroll bar displays correctly only for the `#content` section.

When the content is too tall, the vertical scroll bar appears for the page.  I would like it to only appear in the `#content` section.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use absolute:position for layout.  Use overflow-y:auto to make divs scroll.  Also please put your sample code in the post, not a link.

Comment: Goodjob @Lowkase !
I think your answer is correct.

Comment: i think your solution is the overflow:hidden maybe look at the css overflow for that

Comment: I have a [pen](http://codepen.io/amwill/pen/lmAzb?editors=110) here that uses `absolute` positioning for scrollable content

Comment: Thank you @cocoa.  Following the pen, I was able to get the scroll bars only on the content section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the answer was to use absolute positioning to prevent the page from scrolling vertically.

```
  header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;

    #content {        
      overflow: auto;
    }
  }
```

The only downside that I can see with this approach is that I had to state a height for the header and a top for where the main section was to meet up with it.  This would prevent the header from being sized at run-time.  This seems to be a small price to pay as now both scroll bars can be completely visible at the same time.

Here is the resulting [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkjGhO92MtDDhoAD9Fmu?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have made a working example.

1: Make the body:

```
> overflow: hidden
```

2: Make the area you want to scroll

```
> overflow: scroll
```

Check it out:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o36t0ttz/)